# Using PHP preg_replace() with a string variable, where the variable needs to represent multiple permutations of itself

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

Using:

```
preg_replace(pattern, replacement, subject)
```

I'd like to replace, *case-insensitively*, the text contained in `$My_String`, which I can achieve with:

```
preg_replace('/('.$My_String.')/i', '<strong>$1</strong>', $My_Text);
```

If `$My_String` is **alpha beta gamma delta**, this will identify:

- *alPhA beTa GammA DeLta*
- *aLpHa bEta gAMma delTa*

etc.

---

So far, so good. But any **spaces** and **hyphens** in `$My_String` *must also* be regarded as equivalent.

So the `preg_replace()` function *also* needs to identify case-insensitive versions of this **entire set**:

- alpha beta gamma delta
- alpha beta gamma-delta
- alpha beta-gamma delta
- alpha beta-gamma-delta
- alpha-beta gamma delta
- alpha-beta gamma-delta
- alpha-beta-gamma delta
- alpha-beta-gamma-delta

---

I'm genuinely not sure how to go about this.

I can get as far as:

**1.** Make a copy of `$My_String`:

```
 $My_String_Copy = $My_String
```

**2.** Replace all the spaces with `¦`:

```
 $My_String_Copy = str_replace(' ', '¦', $My_String_Copy);
```

**3.** Replace all hyphens with `¦`:

```
$My_String_Copy = str_replace('-', '¦', $My_String_Copy);
```

**4.** Split `$My_String_Copy` at every occurrence of `¦`:

```
$My_String_Copy_Array = explode('¦', $My_String_Copy);
```

This will give me an array:

```
$My_String_Copy_Array = [

  'Alpha',
  'Beta',
  'Gamma',
  'Delta'

];
```

Which I can repeatedly loop through to derive the **entire set** above, as an array.

After that I can run yet another loop, in which, in each iteration, I can run:

```
preg_replace('/('.$Entire_Set[$i].')/i', '<strong>$1</strong>', $My_Text);
```

targeting, in turn, each element of the **entire set** above.

---

That's as far as I've got. But I'm sure there must be a smarter, more efficient way to go about this.

If I can possibly avoid it, I really **don't want to create an array** containing every single hyphen / space permutation of `$My_String`.

---

### Example Input and Output

**String Variable:**

```
$My_String = 'alpha beta gamma delta';
```

**Input:**

```
My codephrase is alPha Beta-GaMMa deLTa and your codephrase is ALpha-beTA gAmmA-DElta.
```

**Output:**

```html
My codephrase is <strong>alPha Beta-GaMMa deLTa</strong> and your codephrase is <strong>ALpha-beTA gAmmA-DElta</strong>.
```

Comment: You could use preg_split with a pattern `[\h-]+` to split on spaces and hyphens. https://regex101.com/r/Vg3y1D/1 See https://3v4l.org/WLcq5 So you want to place all the words between `<strong>`?

Comment: Can you clarify your desired output? Also including the code you're using, rather than describing it ("which I can repeatedly loop through") would be helpful for attempting to recreate your results. Based on what I can understand, it seems like `preg_replace("/(\w+)\b/i", "<strong>$1</strong>", $My_Text);` should work?

Comment: Re: _"Can you clarify your desired output? "_ Thanks, @miken32. I've extended the question to include an example string variable, input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat spaces and hyphens the same, then simply replacing any occurrence of either with `[ -]` should be sufficient:

```php
$samples = [
    "My codephrase is alPhA beTa GammA DeLta and your codephrase is aLpHa bEta gAMma delTa",
    "My codephrase is alpha beta gamma delta and your codephrase is alpha beta gamma-delta",
    "My codephrase is alpha beta-gamma delta and your codephrase is alpha beta-gamma-delta",
    "My codephrase is alpha-beta gamma delta and your codephrase is alpha-beta gamma-delta",
    "My codephrase is alpha-beta-gamma delta and your codephrase is alpha-beta-gamma-delta",
];

$My_String = "alpha beta gamma delta";

$My_String = str_replace([" ", "-"], "[ -]", $My_String);
foreach ($samples as $My_Text) {
    echo preg_replace("/\b($My_String)\b/i", "<strong>$1</strong>", $My_Text) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```html
My codephrase is <strong>alPhA beTa GammA DeLta</strong> and your codephrase is <strong>aLpHa bEta gAMma delTa</strong>
My codephrase is <strong>alpha beta gamma delta</strong> and your codephrase is <strong>alpha beta gamma-delta</strong>
My codephrase is <strong>alpha beta-gamma delta</strong> and your codephrase is <strong>alpha beta-gamma-delta</strong>
My codephrase is <strong>alpha-beta gamma delta</strong> and your codephrase is <strong>alpha-beta gamma-delta</strong>
My codephrase is <strong>alpha-beta-gamma delta</strong> and your codephrase is <strong>alpha-beta-gamma-delta</strong>
```

Comment: Ohhhh. This is _very_ clever. So... does this mean the regex parser doesn't escape regex characters in `$My_String`? I have to go and try this out right now. If it works, I'm really impressed - this is a very smart workaround.

Comment: It does not do any escaping, which can be a problem when you are working with variable patterns. If you have any special characters in `$My_String` then you would need to escape them before passing to `preg_replace()`.

Comment: Brilliant. You did it. Thank you. I struggled to get `str_replace([" ", "-"], "[ -]", $My_String)` to work because it always wanted to parse `$My_String` twice (presumably once for each element) which led to inner and outer square brackets. But I succeeded with the regex equivalent: `preg_replace('/(.*)[\s-](.*)/', '$1[\s-]$2', $My_String )`.

Comment: Using `str_replace()` is more efficient than running `preg_replace()`. I'm not sure what kind of trouble you're describing, but it wasn't a result of `str_replace()`.

Comment: When I ran `str_replace([" ", "-"], "[ -]", 'alpha-beta')`, I got: `alpha[ [ -]]beta`. We can see what's happening here: First the `-` is rewritten as `[ -]` then, on the second parse, the new `-` is rewritten as `[ -]`.

Comment: Ahaaa. Thank you for drawing my attention back to this last week, @miken32. You were absolutely right. It turned out I had _another_ unrelated issue - in another, completely separate file - which led to the function being run twice. So, yes, using `str_replace()` is definitely the optimal approach.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match the different strings on spaces or hyphens, you can replace in your `$My_String` all spaces and hyphens with `[\h-]+` to match all consecutive permutations of a space and a hyphen in the source string.

The character class `[\h-]+` matches 1 or more times either a `-` or a horizontal whitespace char.

You can wrap the pattern in word boundaries `\b` to prevent a partial match.

If you echo the value of `$My_String`, the regex would look like this, matching either spaces or hyphens.

```
alpha[\h-]+beta[\h-]+gamma[\h-]+delta
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j1w5OD/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/7OXaZ)

For example

```
$My_String = preg_replace("/[\h-]+/", "[\h-]+", "alpha beta gamma delta");

$strings = [
    "My codephrase is alPha Beta-GaMMa deLTa and your codephrase is ALpha-beTA gAmmA-DElta",
    "alpha beta gamma delta",
    "alpha-- -- beta    gamma delta",
    "alpha beta     gamma-delta",
    "alpha beta-gamma delta",
    "alpha beta-gamma-delta",
    "alpha-beta gamma delta",
    "alpha-beta gamma-delta",
    "alpha-beta-gamma delta",
    "alpha-beta-gamma-delta",
    "alpha-beta-gamma-d"
];

foreach ($strings as $str) {    
    $str = preg_replace("/\b$My_String\b/i", "<strong>$0</strong>", $str);
    echo $str . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
My codephrase is <strong>alPha Beta-GaMMa deLTa</strong> and your codephrase is <strong>ALpha-beTA gAmmA-DElta</strong>
<strong>alpha beta gamma delta</strong>
<strong>alpha-- -- beta    gamma delta</strong>
<strong>alpha beta     gamma-delta</strong>
<strong>alpha beta-gamma delta</strong>
<strong>alpha beta-gamma-delta</strong>
<strong>alpha-beta gamma delta</strong>
<strong>alpha-beta gamma-delta</strong>
<strong>alpha-beta-gamma delta</strong>
<strong>alpha-beta-gamma-delta</strong>
alpha-beta-gamma-d
```

Answer (score 0):

I owe gratitude to both `@TheFourthBird` and `@miken32` for their significant help with this problem.

Both their answers are excellent and if I could accept both, I would.

In summary, the correct approach - prior to running `preg_replace()` - is to take the `plaintext` string variable and modify it so that it no longer represents a `plaintext` but a `regex`, instead.

In my final approach in the script I'm working on, I successfully replaced:

```
preg_replace('/('.$My_String.')/i', '<strong>$1</strong>', $My_Text);
```

first with:

```
preg_replace('/(' . preg_replace('/(.*)[\s-](.*)/', '$1[\s-]$2', $My_String) . ')/i', '<strong>$1</strong>', $My_Text);
```

and then - after a bit more prompting from **@miken32** - I was able to create the `regex` even more efficiently using `str_replace` as the *inner function*:

```
preg_replace('/(' . str_replace([" ", "-"], "[ -]", $My_String) . ')/i', '<strong>$1</strong>', $My_Text);
```

Without the help from the two members above, it never would have occurred to me that I could ***nest PHP string replacement functions*** in this manner.